# calling the selected loop element in a method in a .onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I tried to call the method `addProject()` with the the second argument as current selected element in the loop. But the reference of the argument is `null`, when I called `addProject()`.

I think the reference of the current selected argument in the loop is lost when I'm using the `.onclick` button. But how can I give this argument to the method in a different way?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= proj_array.length - 1; i++) {
        var h = document.createElement("h1");
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = proj_array[i].projectdescription;
        h.innerHTML = proj_array[i].projectname;

        $(".projectsList").append(h).append(p);

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.style.width = "70px";
        button.style.height = "27px";
        button.innerHTML = "Add";

        $(button).addClass("enable");
        button.onclick = function () {
            if ($(button).hasClass("enable")) {
                addProject(this, proj_array[i]);
            }
        }
        $(p).append(button);
    }
    $(".projectsList").accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a `data-*` attribute:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
$(button).data('proj', proj_array[i]);
```

In the `onclick` you can retrieve it:

```
if($(this).hasClass("enable")) {
    addProject(this, $(this).data('proj'));
}
```

Also use `$(this)` not `$(button)` in the click handler.

Answer (score 3):

You need a closure:

```
(function(proj) {
    $(button).on('click', function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass("enable") ) {
            addProject(this, proj);     
        }
    });
})(proj_array[i]);
```

Or you could just stick with jQuery and not complicate this too much:

```
$(function() {
    $.each(proj_array, function(i, proj) {
        var h = $('<h1 />', {html: proj.projectdescription}),
            p = $('<p />', {html: proj.projectname}),
            button = $('<button />', {
                                      width  : '70px',
                                      height : '27px',
                                      html   : 'Add',
                                      'class':'enable'
                                     });

        button.on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("enable")) {
                addProject(this, proj);     
            }
        });
        $(p).append(button);
        $(".projectsList").append(h, p).accordion();
    });
});
```

Comment: why is this the case? i can't seem to figure out when a closure is needed and when the variables defined "outside" are also available in inner functions

Comment: In the loop, `i` is changing for every iteration, so you need to capture it in a closure.

Comment: Clever use of `$.each` to "capture" the index and value!